# qvector.h(74) : error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded from Qt's website the version 5.2.1 which says is good to use with mscv2012_64_opengl.

It was working fine until I decided to use the Common Language Runtime Support `/clr` option. I did that because I am using a .dll that acts as a wrapper between C++ and some code I have in C#.

When I build the project I get the following errors

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(74): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>          c:\qt\qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\qtcore\qmap.h(119) : see reference to class template instantiation 'QVector<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=void
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0(903) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,_Ty>(std::allocator<_Ty> &,_Objty *,_V0_t &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<DataColumn_3D>,
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _Objty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _V0_t=DataColumn_3D
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0(903) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,_Ty>(std::allocator<_Ty> &,_Objty *,_V0_t &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<DataColumn_3D>,
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _Objty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _V0_t=DataColumn_3D
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory(433) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::construct<DataColumn_3D,_Valty>(_Ty *,_V0_t &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<DataColumn_3D>,
1>              _Valty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _V0_t=DataColumn_3D
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory(433) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::construct<DataColumn_3D,_Valty>(_Ty *,_V0_t &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<DataColumn_3D>,
1>              _Valty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _V0_t=DataColumn_3D
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory(473) : see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::_Uninit_move<_InIt,_FwdIt,std::allocator<_Ty>,DataColumn_3D>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt,std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc> &,_Valty *,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _FwdIt=DataColumn_3D *,
1>              _InIt=DataColumn_3D *,
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<DataColumn_3D>,
1>              _Valty=DataColumn_3D
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(1561) : see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::_Uninitialized_move<_Iter,DataColumn_3D*,std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt,std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _FwdIt=DataColumn_3D *,
1>              _Iter=DataColumn_3D *,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<DataColumn_3D>,
1>              _InIt=DataColumn_3D *
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(1504) : see reference to function template instantiation 'DataColumn_3D *std::vector<_Ty>::_Umove<DataColumn_3D*>(_Iter,_Iter,DataColumn_3D *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _Iter=DataColumn_3D *
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(1504) : see reference to function template instantiation 'DataColumn_3D *std::vector<_Ty>::_Umove<DataColumn_3D*>(_Iter,_Iter,DataColumn_3D *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D,
1>              _Iter=DataColumn_3D *
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(1500) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<_Ty>::_Reallocate(unsigned __int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(961) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<_Ty>::_Reallocate(unsigned __int64)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D
1>          ]
1>          DataSource.cpp(256) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=DataColumn_3D
1>          ]
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(133): error C2182: 'at' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(134): error C2182: '[]' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(135): error C2182: '[]' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(136): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(137): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(138): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(139): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(140): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(148): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(150): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(151): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(152): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(153): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(182): error C2182: 'x' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(183): error C2182: 'x' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(189): error C2182: 'first' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(190): error C2182: 'first' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(191): error C2182: 'last' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(192): error C2182: 'last' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(193): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(194): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(198): error C2182: 'defaultValue' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(204): error C2182: 'reference' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(205): error C2182: 'const_reference' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(210): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(211): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(216): error C2182: 'front' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(225): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\include\QtCore/qvector.h(227): error C2182: 't' : illegal use of type 'void'
```

Does anyone here has an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: go to your project properties and in the general section of configuration properties make sure common language runtime support is set clr, i am also assuming that you have already built qt with visual studio

Comment: @decoherence I did not built qt with VS2012 myself, I downloaded it from Qt's website. In the configuration properties Common Language Runtime Support is set to `clr`

Comment: @BRabbit27 you will have to build it yourself

Comment: @PeterDuniho Don't know how c# got in the tags, sorry about that. I edited the post.

Comment: @decoherence I have to build Qt myself with `clr` in order to solve this problem?

Comment: follow http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html, it resolved the problem for me in the past

Comment: @decoherence unless I forgot something while compiling it didn't work ... any special option in the configuration that I need?

Answer (score 0):

From FAQ:

[Is there any way to compile the Qt source code and Qt applications with /clr flag?](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#Is_there_any_way_to_compile_the_Qt_source_code_and_Qt_applications_with_.2Fclr_flag.3F)

> We don't support building Qt or Qt applications with CLR directly. To integrate existing components you can use the [Active Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt.html) framework, which allows integration of Active X and COM object in Qt applications.

Comment: @Dimitry Sokolov The link to Active Qt is broken. [This one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-index.html) works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, replace `<QtXXX>` with your Module.

```
#pragma unmanaged
#include <QtXXX>
#pragma managed
```