# Is it possible to use a DLL that requires common language runtime (/clr) in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, clr

Firstly, I don't have a great knowledge of C++ but have been getting by at work creating some data acquisition and hardware control system using Qt. This uses many different external libraries (.dll/.lib).

I've now come to a point where I need to implement a new library, however I'm having a lot of trouble. I've been given some code which successfully calls functions in the .dll I've been provided in Visual Studio 2015 x86. My aim is to get this code working in Qt 5.6 (MSVC 2015 x86).

The DLL will not work successfully unless I add the /clr and /Gd flags during compilation. I don't have a good understanding of how Qt works on the backend, but comments online suggest Qt doesn't really like /clr. Despite this, when just compiling the code relating to the library, it works great in Qt and I can access the dll functions using loadlibrary(). When introducing other parts of the code such as QCustomPlot, I get serious errors:

[image: Compilation error]

[image: Error in qvector.h]

I have very little idea about this other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610546/qvector-h74-error-c2182-t-illegal-use-of-type-void) which does not look great for an easy solution.

A quick look at my .pro file to give you an idea:

```
QT += widgets core gui printsupport
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Example3
DESTDIR = Release
CONFIG += release
DEFINES += _WINDOWS WIN64
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -clr -Gd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_STL_ON -= -EHsc
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_EXCEPTIONS_ON -= -EHsc
PRECOMPILED_HEADER = stdafx.h

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
        libray.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        stdafx.cpp \
        qcustomplot.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
            library.h \
            stdafx.h \
            qcustomplot.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

The stdafx.h file contains `#include <tchar.h>` and `#include <comdef.h>`.

Could someone potentially explain what I'm seeing here and if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: I doubt that it's a good idea to use CLR stuff directly in Qt. Qt very probably doesn't "know" anything about managed code. I would suggest to put your CLR stuff into a non-CLR wrapper. Actually, I don't know how to do this but, out of curiosity, I did [google "c++ using clr dll with non-clr dll"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+using+clr+dll+with+non-clr+dll) and found e.g. [C++ CLR DLL function export](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/03a10031-7077-41b9-83bd-7e7d4e0ca1f3/c-clr-dll-function-export?forum=vclanguage) on MSDN which might be interesting.

Comment: Have you tried Active Qt? Your link says that would be the solution.